# .htaccess redirect file with extensions to error page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

before to start asking i want to say that i tried to search everywere and i didn't found anything so...

My problem is that i want to have change first.html second.html and so on to first second without extensions and i use this:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

and now i have my files without extensions, now i want that when someone write first.html or second.html send it to error page, now my code is the following:

```
ErrorDocument 404 errore/errore.html

Options +MultiViews
```

Hope you help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove file extensions from urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869242/remove-file-extensions-from-urls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+[^\?]+\.(html|php)
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

This rewrite rule (you'll need `RewriteEngine On` if you don't already have that in your htaccess file) matches direct requests to anything that ends with the extension `.html` or `.php` and flags the request as a 404 response using the `R=404` rewrite flag.

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Perfect, if i want to make this rule valid to php too? and explanation please

Comment: @JonLin sorry, yesterday i thought that is worked but non properly, it' only write the path where is the error and dont link to it. Actually is writing errore/errore.html on the body